# SyntaxError File "import.py", line 14

Tags: python

```
def division_title(initial):
    n = initial.split()
    if len(n) == 3 :
    return n
    else return [n[0],None,n[1]]
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTi7c.png)

Comment: You have several issues. `=` is for assignment, `==` is for checking equality. You also have a missing colon or two and your indentation is incorrect

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  Your posted code has multiple problems, and you failed to include your error message within your post.  External links are not acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write it as follows.

```
def division_title(initial):
    n = initial.split()
    if len(n) == 3:
     return n
```

Comment: This is not correct python syntax